# How to run Android application on Windows?

Tags: windows, android

I do not have any Android device however I want to try some Android applications on my Windows PC. What options do I have?

I already installed [Android-x86 Project](http://www.Android-x86.org/) on Virtual PC however when I tried download application from Android market I've got following message:

```
There are no Android phones associated with this account.
```

Comment: did you create a google account for your virtual android device?

Comment: @Kyle: I am not sure what you mean. I have extra google account for this task however it's not associated with my virtual android device. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Okay these steps may differ but goto settings>accounts and sync> add account

Comment: Your title needs rephrased. You're asking how to download android apps from the marketplace with a pc, correct?

Comment: @Kyle: In my version that menu contains only some exchane stuff.

Comment: @Blomkvist: No, I wanted to run application, market is only obvious place from where I tried to obtain application. Luckily enough I wasn't only place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Android apps on PC through Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1044567/how-to-run-android-apps-on-pc-through-google-chrome)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot download apps from the Android Market website.  You can only select apps to be installed on a device that has recently used the Market app, using the same Google account that you are logged into the website with.

I recomend using the Android emulator rather than the Android-x86 project.  Regardless, neither has the Market, but apps can be installed from other sources.  [This answer on Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/how-can-i-add-the-market-to-my-device/4299#4299) links to some information on that, and the Android x86 project [also has info on installing apps](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/apphowto).

Comment: +1 for installing apps on the emulator see http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/run-android-applications-on-pc-with-emulator also note that apparently the Amazon Android App store apparently can be easily loaded onto the emulator (if you're in the US) http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7879/can-i-use-android-emulator-to-get-the-free-apps-from-amazons-app-store

Comment: Metthew is right, there is no market for me (officially). Fortunately enough I have direct link to `.apk` file, so after enabling unknown sources everything works right.

Answer (score 1):

[BlueStacks App Player](http://www.bluestacks.com/) is the best tool I've found for running Android apps on a PC (as opposed to emulating an Android device, for example because you are writing an app and want to see what it would look like on a phone). It's free and has very good compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run android apps while running windows, you should use [Bluestacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/) or [Nox](https://downloadnox.com/). I prefer Bluestacks.

If you want to run a full android software on your PC, I would recommend [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) or [Remix OS](http://www.jide.com/remixos).