# How to run Android apps on PC through Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, android

There are many way to run an android application on pc (e.g : genymotion , by installing android through virtual machine).But my question look different: Is that possible to run Android apps using my browser google chrome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Is it possible to run Android apps using my browser google chrome?

Yes, using Google's `ARC Welder`

- `ARC Welder` is a tool to help you test and publish your Android Apps to Chrome OS using the App Runtime for Chrome (beta), ARC.
- See [Getting Started with ARC](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc) and "How to Use Google’s ARC Welder to Run Android Apps in Chrome" below for more detailed instructions.
- There is an [Official App Compatibility List](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iIbxaftAu_ho5rv9fUlXSLTzwU6MbKOldsWXyrYiyo8/htmlview?usp=sharing&sle=true):

  [image]

---

#### How to Use Google’s ARC Welder to Run Android Apps in Chrome

> Google recently released an ARC Welder Chrome app, which allows you to
>   run Android apps if you’re on Chrome OS, or using the Chrome web
>   browser.
>
> ARC or App Runtime for Chrome is in beta and so you should expect
>   bugs. Also, you simply can’t install apps from the Google Play Store.
>   You need an Android application package or APK, or an Android
>   application that has been stored in a ZIP file.
>
> In order to run APK files, you have to first download them from one of
>   any number of repositories on the Internet. Once downloaded, you can
>   load them in ARC Welder and if (big “IF”) it runs, test it out.
>
> There’s no guarantee all (or any) of the apps you try will work or
>   that they’ll be usable, but for developers who want to create Android
>   apps that also run in Chrome OS and the Chrome browser, it’s useful
>   for testing.
>
> For the rest of us, it’s just fun to play around and see how it works.
>
> **Installing ARC Welder on Your System**
>
> You will find [ARC Welder in the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/arc-welder/emfinbmielocnlhgmfkkmkngdoccbadn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher). Click the
>   “Install” button to get started.
>
> [image]
>
> Click “Add” to install the ARC Welder into your Chrome apps.
>
> [image]
>
> Once the Arc Welder app is added, you will have to find some APKs to
>   run. There are a lot places from which you can download APK files. Try
>   searching for specific apps along with “APK”.
>
> When you’ve found some, open Chrome, your Chrome Apps, and then start
>   ARC Welder.
>
> [image]
>
> When you first run it, you’ll need to select a directory the APK can
>   be written to. Click “Choose” and then either select an existing
>   location or create a new one.
>
> [image]
>
> Next, it’s time to load your first APK. Click “Add your APK” to begin.
>
> [image]
>
> Navigate to the folder where you saved your APK files and select one.
>   Now you’ll be presented with quite a few options, such as how you want
>   the orientation, any metadata you want to add, etc.
>
> Don’t worry if you don’t want to mess with any of this, just leave all
>   of it to the defaults and click “Launch App”.
>
> Most of these options are self-explanatory. For the purposes of just
>   trying stuff out, we don’t need to mess with any of it.
>
> [image]
>
> Chances are quite good that many of the APKs you try to load will not
>   work. We tried to load Facebook and Google Play, but both seemed to
>   hang. We gave Flappy Birds a shot for old times’ sake, but it crashed.
>
> Twitter worked, however, as did Instagram, and a few others.
>
> It’s kind of nice being able to use the Instagram app (versus the
>   horrible website) on a regular computer.
>
> If you load an Android app in Chrome, it will be available to load
>   directly as a Chrome app from thereon. No need to load it through ARC
>   Welder.
>
> [image]
>
> After successfully loading Twitter, it is available to use as a
>   Twitter client.
>
> You can, however, only test one Android app at a time. The next time
>   you load an APK from ARC Welder, it will remove the previous app.
>
> [image]
>
> Nevertheless, it’s interesting to be able to load Android apps, not
>   simply on Chrome OS, which seems a more natural fit, but on Windows,
>   OS X, or any other system with the Chrome browser on it.

Source [How to Use Google’s ARC Welder to Run Android Apps in Chrome](http://www.howtogeek.com/214734/how-to-use-googles-arc-welder-to-run-android-apps-in-chrome/)

Comment: @GAD3R Added [Official App Compatibility List](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iIbxaftAu_ho5rv9fUlXSLTzwU6MbKOldsWXyrYiyo8/htmlview?usp=sharing&sle=true#) link to answer

Comment: I think that not is good, because more apps need permisions "google" for example "hearthstone, clash of clans/royale" and never executed, I tried it !

Comment: @DavidPostill I have imported the apk and tested the app. It works, thank you. Anyway, what can I do with the ZIP file? Is it the installation archive for Chromebooks?

Comment: @DavidPostill so how Chromebooks users can install my app? Have I to send the ZIP file to them?

Comment: @smartmouse Well you need to send something to them. I don't know enough about Android applications or Chromebooks to say more than that. Perhaps you should ask a new question about this?

Comment: Since the ZIP file is a convertion of an Android app made by me, maybe I can publish the ZIP file here: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish

Comment: @smartmouse I've already suggested you should ask a **new** question.

Answer (score 1):

ARC wilder uses so much space inside chrome and while starting chrome it takes a lot of time for minimum configuration machines.

Try a virtual machine of android.

https://www.manymo.com/

Better use system installed apps.

BlueStack, Windroy & Android x-86 by installing on the system.